# how to authenticate/authorize fetchr requests

Tags: fluxible, fetchr

How can I expose the req.session server side to the fetchr service requests so that I can authorize the requests?  Can I have access the the session or the request object somehow from the crud methods?

An alternative to session would be to set a bearer token on the client side and pass that in as well.  However, this would make it difficult for isomorphic rendering as we wouldn't have access to that token server side.

Are there any simple fluxible fetchr examples requiring authenticated services, e.g. read myAccount?